# Sending complex JSON object to MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Actually, I have a fingerprint minutiae object, generated in the client side of my application.
I obtain this object using the java script , it is a "complex object"

I tried to send it to the server using the ajax syntax

```
$.ajax({
            //   url: baseUri+'HomeController/saveexpense',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetFingerPrint", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
           // dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ obj: fmdTest }),
            success: function(result) {


            }
        });
```

this worked great for me when obj:SimpleObject , but with my new complex object, debugging shows me that the object contains only {} (i.e. empty)

I think the problem is because my object is now a complex object not a simple one

also

```
data: JSON.stringify(fmdTest),
```

didn't work
any solution?

Comment: Can you explain the structure of `fmdTest`?

Comment: it is an instance of a class called Fmd, designed by the fingerprint sensor manufacturers he is a picture for it
http://oi45.tinypic.com/64p25j.jpg

Comment: and this is for it is base types 
http://oi50.tinypic.com/a4v51w.jpg

Comment: Can you show what sort of debugging you used to determine that the object (*which object?*) is `{}`?

Comment: I have used the IE debugger, and watched the network traffic in the request message.

Comment: During further search in the internet, I have read that the cause of the problem is that my model object (Fmd) doesn't have a parameterless constructor (In-fact it doesn't have any constructor since it uses the abstract factory design pattern), What is really interesting is that I have no access to the code, since it is a ready made package (dlls) by the programmers of the library.
Any Solution\?!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved the problem, according to what I have read, JSON do not have any problems for stringfying any object as long as it has a parameter-less constructor needed in the de-serialization process) however, fortunately i found that the manufacturer provided some method to serialize my fmd.